# El login de mi aplicación unicamente funciona en emulador. Android Studio

Tags: php, android, android-studio, webservice, login

la cuestión es que tengo una base de datos alojada en Hostinger que contiene los datos de usuarios para un login en mi aplicación en Android Studio, aparte un código php para enviar el dato por Json y un código para la autenticacion, todo en teoría correcto, el problema viene siendo que esta autenticacion solo es válida si trabajo en emulador, si trabajo con la app directamente en un teléfono, nunca reconoce los datos. Tengo los permisos de Internet y la llamada a la base de datos. El código lee si la variable "res" recibida por JSON es 0 o 1 y de ese modo hace la autenticación. Adjunto código:

```
   ingresar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Thread tr=new Thread(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    final String res=enviarPost(txtCor.getText().toString(),txtPas.getText().toString());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            int r = objJSON(res);
                            if (r>0){
                                Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(i);
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Usuario o Contraseña Incorrecta",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
            tr.start();

        }
    });


public String enviarPost(String cor, String pas){
    //este metodo busca los JSON
    String parametros="cor="+cor+"&pas="+pas;
    HttpURLConnection conection=null;
    String respuesta="";
    try{
        URL url=new URL("http://mipagina/valida.php/");
        conection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        conection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",""+Integer.toString(parametros.getBytes().length));

        conection.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr=new DataOutputStream(conection.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(parametros);
        wr.close();


        Scanner inStream=new Scanner(conection.getInputStream());

        while(inStream.hasNextLine())
            respuesta+=(inStream.nextLine());
    }catch (Exception e){}
    return respuesta;
}

public int objJSON(String respuesta){
    int res=0;
    try{
        JSONArray json=new JSONArray(respuesta);
        if (json.length() > 0){
            res=1;
        }
    }catch (Exception e){}
    return res;
}
```

Comment: ¿ has revisado el LogCat, que mensaje se muestra?

Comment: Malcon!!!, te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, por lo tanto **te sugiero modificar tu pregunta para evitar sea cerrada**, saludos!

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Android corre tu emulador y cuál tu móvil? ¿Podrías decirnos qué excepción está soltando? Para verlo cambia tus `}catch (Exception e){}` por `}catch (Exception e){ Toast mensaje = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getLocalizedMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);mensaje.show();}` o bien por un `}catch (Exception e){ Log.d("Excepción", e.getLocalizedMessage()); }`. Con eso último en el log de ejecución aparecerá una línea que empieza por `D/Excepción: (mensaje de la excepción)`.